# Can I wax these specific blue parts of my motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, paint, preventive-maintenance, wax

So I got overwhelmed by many doubts regarding waxing. I'm new to riding and maintenance.

This is my first motorcycle. It has a metal fuel tank with glossy blue metallic **paint**.

[image]

The non metal parts (highlighted by **yellow** arrows) also have exact same "color". I'm not even sure what they are made of. But sure they are non metal and just like some plastic.

So as you can see:

***Metal part:** Fuel tank, front mudguard*

***Non metal parts:** Shrouds, side panels (parts which have white & black stickers on it) and probably headlight body too*

Here's inside photo of one of those non metal parts of motorcycle:

[image]

This is how it looks from outside:

[image]

This is true for all those yellow highlighted parts I've shown in beginning. Inside they are black, outside they are glossy blue. **And they are not made from any metal. Looks like plastic.**

So I'm not at all sure if it's some blue plastic or this blue layer is also a blue paint just like fuel tank.

Now, I was looking some liquid wax products online and many of them had written specification like "Suitable for paintworks" or "For paint finishes".

**Given all that, can I apply liquid wax on these non metal blue (yellow highlighted) parts?**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, those parts can certainly be waxed and it will help protect the finish.

Be careful not to get the wax on the black textured pieces however.  After it dries it will turn whitish and will mar the look of those parts.  It's hard to remove from matte or textured surfaces.

Comment: Thanks. Slightly off the post query:  Any idea those plastic parts of my bike are actually blue painted (just like metal fuel tank) or the blue is some other kind of stuff?

Comment: In my experience most such parts are painted.  Otherwise it's nearly impossible to get a color match between the painted metal parts and the plastic parts.

Comment: Oh yeah, the colors are absolutely same and same gloss/shine. I have to tap them to figure out they are non-metal. Otherwise you can't tell.

Comment: Also, the front mudguard has black color in bottom side, but I guess it's same thing as blue. That can also be waxed right? I mean it's black but it's not textured like you said, so it's safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wax on parts highlighted with the Yellow arrow. Just don't use it on the unpainted plastic parts like the side panels of your bike. You can use dashboard polish for plastic parts like mudguards and side panels.